# How to checkout any item/file through other users account or system account

Tags: sharepoint-online, check-out, communication-site

I need a solution that every contributor can check out a file. the file needs to be checked out using system account and only Admins can revert this operation and make the file editable again for all.

I know that this is available OOTB using in place record management feature but need to bring it on the list view itself. There is no rest api call to make it possible (to my knowledge). Any work-arounds would be appriciated

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Document library settings -> Manage files which have no checked in version" -> select files and check Take Ownership of Selection. Now the files would be visible.

Comment: Need to do it pragmatically specially through Rest Api or through JSOM